# How to include crossrefs in bib files generated by biber --output-format=bibtex

Tags: biber

## The Question

How can I ensure that cross-referenced entries are included in a `.bib` file generated by `biber` for a document in case the document does not cite the cross-referenced entries themselves but only entries referring to them? To be clear, I don't want the cross-referenced entries to appear separately in the list of references but I need them in the`.bib` file so that complete data is available for the entries I do cite.

## Background

Consider the following document which uses a regular database of bibliography entries (included here as `orig.bib`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
  \bibliography{orig}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{orig.bib}
@bookinbook{author-bk1,
  crossref = {author-bigbk},
  title = {Originally a Separate Book},
  pages = {345--789}}

@suppbook{author-essays-intro,
  crossref = {author-essays},
  title = {Introduction},
  pages = {1--8}}

@incollection{author-essay,
  crossref = {editor-collection},
  title = {My Essay},
  pages = {8-34},
  author = {Author, Bit Busy}}

@book{author-bigbk,
  author = {Author, Prolific},
  title = {Collected Works},
  year = 1453,
  publisher = {Printers 'R Us},
  address = {Milky Way}}

@book{author-essays,
  title = {Essays},
  author = {Author, Busy},
  year = 1578,
  publisher = {We Print 4U},
  address = {Alpha Centauri}}

@book{editor-collection,
  editor = {Editor, Fair},
  booktitle = {Collection of People's Thoughts},
  year = 1679,
  publisher = {Great Collections in Print},
  address = {Earth}}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\autocites{author-bk1,author-essays-intro,author-essay}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

As expected, this produces the following:

[image: Complete reference list]

## The Promise

Now suppose that I want to generate a `.bib` file containing just those entries needed for this particular document. (Obviously this would be pointless with this example since `orig.bib` contains nothing else, but that's not typically the case, of course.)

Turning to `biber`'s manual, I find this:

> **3.1.1 The output_format option**
>
> Biber is able to output ... BibTeX .bib files. .bib output is possible
>   in tool mode, when you are converting an entire datasource file
>   independently of any particular document (see section 3.12). It is
>   also useful when you want, instead of a .bbl, a new .bib file
>   containing only the cited entries from a document so that you can, for
>   example, send a minimally complete  package for typesetting to
>   someone. To do this, you would, after the first LaTeX run, call Biber
>   like this:
>
> ```
> biber --output_format=bibtex test.bcf
> ```
>
> This would result in a new .bib file called test_biber.bib containing all cited entries in
>   test.tex, in citation order, formatted according to the various ouput_* options.

So I try this:

```
biber --output_format=bibtex prawf3.bcf
```

## The Problem

My attempt creates `prawf3_biber.bib`:

```
@BOOKINBOOK{author-bk1,
  CROSSREF = {author-bigbk},
  PAGES    = {345--789},
  TITLE    = {Originally a Separate Book},
}

@SUPPBOOK{author-essays-intro,
  CROSSREF = {author-essays},
  PAGES    = {1--8},
  TITLE    = {Introduction},
}

@INCOLLECTION{author-essay,
  AUTHOR   = {Author, Bit Busy},
  CROSSREF = {editor-collection},
  PAGES    = {8-34},
  TITLE    = {My Essay},
}
```

which is obviously not what you would hope for since using this `.bib` file will clearly not yield the required results. That is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
  \bibliography{prawf3_biber}

\begin{document}

\autocites{author-bk1,author-essays-intro,author-essay}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

will encounter problems when `biber` is run:

```
INFO - Found 3 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'prawf3_biber.bib' for section 0
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'prawf3_biber.bib'
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for crossref 'author-bigbk' in entry 'author-bk1' - ignoring (section 0)
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for crossref 'author-essays' in entry 'author-essays-intro' - ignoring (section 0)
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for crossref 'editor-collection' in entry 'author-essay' - ignoring (section 0)
```

which is obviously only to be expected given that the cross-referenced entries are not there.

`biber`'s manual does discuss using crossref data when in `tool` mode but that seems to apply only when converting an entire datasource. So if I wanted to apply that to `orig.bib`, I could do that and then I could extract the (now complete) entries into `prawf3_biber.bib` using the above command. [At least, I assume I could - I haven't tested.]

## The Question Revisited

But how can I ensure the entries in the generated `.bib` file are completed with data from the cross-referenced entries *without* converting the original `.bib` file and *without* citing the cross-referenced entries in the document?

Comment: @jon Thanks. That's pretty much what I did except without automation. I temporarily added the `crossref` entries as `\nocite` in the document, re-latexed etc. with the original `.bib` datasources and then extracted a complete `.bib` with `biber --output-format=bibtex`. It isn't a very satisfactory approach, though. It is surprising `biber` can't do this. It just seems so powerful and this seems pretty basic. Also, the documentation doesn't even hint at this deficiency which seems somewhat remiss. Moreover, `biber` can do this when transforming datasources so I thought there must be a way....

Comment: @jon Finally figured it out - see my answer below (if interested).  I have no idea if anybody else will find this useful or not but since I asked...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally figured out how to do this. In the documentation, it looks as if using the `--output_format` in the way I was is distinct from invoking `tool` mode. So the way `crossref` data is treated there doesn't seem relevant to the case of concern here. However,

```
biber --help
```

is rather more helpful. In particular, it states that `--output_format=bibtex` *only makes sense in `tool` mode*. So, since that option is clearly intended for use in this sort of case, as the documentation suggests, it must make sense to use `tool` mode here, too. Moreover, the command help is also a whole lot simpler to understand for relatively simple uses. Whereas the documentation on `tool` mode goes into great detail about configuring the right kinds of processing for different datasource transformations, the command help clarifies the basic options better.

In particular, it turns out that there is an option to do just what is wanted here:

```
biber --output_format=bibtex --output_resolve prawf3.bcf
```

What this does is not include the cross-referenced entries in the resulting `.bib`. What it does instead is *complete* the entries which use them with data from the cross-referenced entries. The resulting `prawf3_biber.bib`:

```
@BOOKINBOOK{author-bk1,
  AUTHOR     = {Author, Prolific},
  BOOKAUTHOR = {Author, Prolific},
  BOOKTITLE  = {Collected Works},
  LOCATION   = {Milky Way},
  PAGES      = {345--789},
  PUBLISHER  = {Printers 'R Us},
  TITLE      = {Originally a Separate Book},
  YEAR       = {1453},
}

@SUPPBOOK{author-essays-intro,
  AUTHOR     = {Author, Busy},
  BOOKAUTHOR = {Author, Busy},
  BOOKTITLE  = {Essays},
  LOCATION   = {Alpha Centauri},
  PAGES      = {1--8},
  PUBLISHER  = {We Print 4U},
  TITLE      = {Introduction},
  YEAR       = {1578},
}

@INCOLLECTION{author-essay,
  AUTHOR    = {Author, Bit Busy},
  BOOKTITLE = {Collection of People's Thoughts},
  EDITOR    = {Editor, Fair},
  LOCATION  = {Earth},
  PAGES     = {8-34},
  PUBLISHER = {Great Collections in Print},
  TITLE     = {My Essay},
  YEAR      = {1679},
}
```

which is actually better for many purposes than including the cross-referenced entries separately.

Comment: +1. So, it's really just a kind of RTFM!  (Annoying that I have used `biber --help` before and just never noticed, or, worse, thought to look this time.)  Anyway, I guess it's good to have both a complete-the-references version since that would be much harder to do 'by hand' than my add-the-crossrefs-as-is workaround.

Comment: @jon Interesting. It never occurred to me before to try `biber --help`. I don't know why I did it. I just kept looking in the manual. I guess it is really a kind of DRTM - RTFH! That said, I'm sure this information must be *somewhere* in the manual. I think that really the example use of `biber` to generate a document-specific `.bib` file should include `--output_resolve` or, at the very least, mention it. After all, the use of `crossref` is common and you won't get a 'minimally complete package' without the option. I don't know generally but I do think the manual is pretty poor on this point.

Comment: @jon I only saw it in relation to `tool` mode which the description of generating the doc-specific `.bib` made me think was distinct. Did you find it somewhere else? (The manual is quite long, there are a lot of manuals, life is quite short...)

Comment: @jon Ah, right. I see. I do think the documentation could be improved... I agree that sometimes a solution which keeps the entries separate would be useful although generally I think using the data to complete the cited entries will often work at least as well, sometimes better. It is more concise for sending with a file if the point is just to enable typesetting, for example.

Answer (score 5):

If at all possible, cfr's answer is to be preferred for obvious reasons (esp. convenience).

However, if one needs to avoid how Biber 'resolves' crossref-ed entries and keep all entries separate -- e.g., perhaps because you cite several articles from one collection of essays and you therefore need still to have each essay merely point to the book in the bibliography rather than each provide the full bibliographical reference -- then you could do something like this:

```sh
latex      basefile.tex 
biber -m 1 basefile.bcf     # `--mincrossref | -m 1` produces a .bbl with all the references
bbl2nocite basefile tmpfile # see below
latex      basefile.tex
biber --output_format=bibtex basefile.bcf # produces `basefile_biber.bib`
```

In order for this to work, you need to `\input` what you are extracting from the `.bbl` somehow.  I did this with a mindless `bbl2nocite` script, which is essentially just wrapping up `grep` and `sed`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#
# Find and convert all lines in a .bbl file from
# \entry{<key>}{<entrytype>}{}
# to
# \nocite{<key>}
#
# usage: bbl2nocite inputfile outputfile
INFILE=$1
OUTFILE=$2

grep '\\entry' $INFILE.bbl | sed 's/\\entry/\\nocite/g' | sed 's/}{.*/}/' > $OUTFILE.tex
```

The other modification you need to make is in the `.tex`: you need to `\input` what I called `tmpfile.tex` above.  Using cfr's example file, all you need to add is:

```
\input{tmpfile}
```

right before the `\printbibliography`; or you could do instead:

```
\InputIfFileExists{tmpfile.tex}{\input{tmpfile}}{\relax}
```

And, finally, you get the new bibliography file, which ends `_biber.bib`, which should contain, in this case, six entries.

One last thing to note is that you might need to comment out the `\Input...` line and run through a sequence of `latex`, `biber`, and `latex` again to get back to the original appearance of the bibliography.  In cfr's file above, e.g., this technique will lead to having all six items showing up in the bibliography, which may not be wanted.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of the `-m 1` option. That seems useful!